# Ajax-loaded popup image is not always clearing when div emptied

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

I made an image previewer that gives a popup of an image when you hover on that link.  It works but sometimes it will fail to `.empty` the div when I stop hovering over the link.  I will ocassionally get the previous image, the error text, or two images.  If I hover again it is fixed.  This happens maybe 10% of the time.  Also I can't get the height of the div.  I don't know if this is also related.

```
$('<div/>',{
   'id' : 'popup'
    }).appendTo('body');

function showError() {
    $('<div/>').text('Picture Not Found').appendTo('#popup');
    $('#popup').show();
};


function getImage() {
        $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: link,
        error: function(){
            showError();
        },
        success: function(data) {
            var styleText = $('style', data).text();
            var imageRegex = /background-image: url\('[^']+/;
            var imageMatch = styleText.match(imageRegex);
            if (imageMatch) {
                var image = imageMatch[0].replace(/background-image: url\('/, ''); 
                $('#popup').append('<img src="' + image + '" style="padding:0px" alt="">');
            } else {
                showError();
            };

        }
     });
};

$('a').filter(function() {
    return /users\/\d+\/pictures/.test(this.href);
    }).removeAttr('title').hover(function(e) {

    link = this.href.replace('http://', 'https://');
    getImage();
    $('#popup').show();
    height = $('#popup').outerHeight();
    console.log(height);

    }, function() {
        $('#popup').empty().hide();

    })
});
```

Comment: The reason the ajax request looks weird is because I don't have access to the html or css and they store the url in `<style>` tags.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it was an issue with triggering a hover event when passing over the link quickly.  Seems to be fixed by adding a delay to the hover.

Here is a link to a guide that helped.
http://jelaniharris.com/2008/adding-a-delay-to-jquery-functions/

I also changed it to a separate div for the error message so I could just change the src of the image rather than empty the div.   I think that makes it a little faster.